# Read this using php

Tags: php

Is there any way to read/write the following data using php? And what is this called?

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like data serialized by the PHP [serialize()](http://www.php.net/serialize) function. You can read it using [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/unserialize).

```
$serialized = 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}';
$data = unserialize($serialized);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 2):

try using unserialize() if that is a serialized data then that should unserialize it.

Answer (score 2):

Yep... That's serialized data. You can unserialize it for pure chechup purposes here - [**http://unserialize.net/serialize**](http://unserialize.net/serialize).

Other than that use [**unserialize()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) in your PHP code.